# Check that function return types match the def statements in PR test in python

Tags: python, types, automated-tests, pytest, pull-request

I have a Github Action that runs unit tests on each Pull Request (PR).

It effectively runs `pytest`.

Seeing that we leverage the type hints introduced in [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/), I'd like a method like this to cause a PR check fail:

```py
def return_an_int() -> int:
  return 'not an int'
```

Is there a simple way to run such a "compilation" test (I know python is interpreted) for all the `.py` files in the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the kind of type checking that `mypy` does, so you could include running `mypy` in your Action workflow.

If your module and its dependencies are already installed in your workflow, this step should do the trick:

```
      - name: Run mypy
        run: |
          # needed if mypy isn't already installed
          pip install mypy
          # "mypy somedir" looks for and checks all Python files under somedir
          # I assume your code is in some source directory <src-dir>
          mypy <src-dir>
```

And that should be all you need, placed after the steps that install your code base.

Comment: would you mind recommending a full `mypy` command for answer acceptance?